# Is it practical to write firefox extensions in Dart?

Tags: firefox-addon, dart

This is a basic question, rather then using Javascript I would like to use Dart to write a firefox extension. Even if I could do it, I might not be able to do it, it might take ten times the effort of using javascript thus not be practical.

Answer (score -1):

Well in the end you're compiling to JavaScript. If the extension is small then it would not be practical as the compiled version will have a lot of lines of code and the size will be bigger than normal.

Comment: Does code size actually matter for a browser extension? It's not like a website where the code has to be sent over the network each time. Obviously, smaller is better, but I doubt the overhead caused by dart2js is enough to cause any problems for this scenario.

Comment: I see it as not practical but I guess it doesnt matter too much unless the dart2js compiled code runs significantly slower. Anyways OP I would try it out and report back to us.